# Use for loop to iterate from 0 to 100 and print the sum of all evens and the sum of all odds with JavaScript Loops

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to answer for this question:
"Use for loop to iterate from 0 to 100 and print the sum of all evens and the sum of all odds."

and my code is:

```
numbersE = []
numbersO = []
let sumE = 0
let sumO = 0


for (i=0;i<=100;i++) {

    if(i % 2 == 0){
        numbersE.push(i)
     }

    else {
        numbersO.push(i)
        
    }
    
    sumE += numbersE[i]
    sumO += numbersO[i]
}

console.log(sumE, sumO)

Nan Nan
```

where is the my mistake ?

Comment: 0 to 100 but your loop is from 0 to 10

Comment: There are a few. 1) You stop at 10. 2) Why are you creating arrays? 3) If you push into an array, for example, the value 2 will not be stored at position 2. ... Just add the numbers in the loop.

Comment: I was trying small numbers first then it stayed 10. I'll fix it now.

Comment: I'm beginner for JavaSciprt can you show me on the code, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let's start with the loop. At i=0, if statement is triggered and 0 is pushed to the array numbersE and hence sumE = 0. But the array numbersO is empty because the for loop didn't push any values to numbersO. Therefore at i=0, sumO returns **NaN**.
2. Similarly when i>0, you are trying to access the index of arrays numbersE, numbersO which does not exist. For example, at i=10, 10%2 equals 0, hence 10 is pushed to the array numbersE. And your code adds an element from the array numbersE with index 10 to the variable sumE and stores it in sumE. But the problem here is that the array numbersE doesn't have an element at index 10.  Hence it returns **NaN**.

This can be solved by:

```js
let i;
let sumE = 0;
let sumO = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  i % 2 === 0 ? (sumE += i) : (sumO += 1);
}

console.log(sumE, sumO);
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
let sumE = 0
let sumO = 0

// You could technically start at 1 here
for (let i = 0; i <= 100; i++) {
  // Just add the numbers without using arrays
  if (i % 2 == 0) {
    sumE += i
  } else {
    sumO += i
  }
}

console.log(sumE, sumO)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100];
let even = 0;
let odd = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
if(i % 2 === 0) {
even += arr[i];
} else {
odd += arr[i];
}
} 
console.log([even, odd]);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).